# Dynamic manipulation of font components

Tags: java, fonts

I am developing an application to dynamically change the components of a font which is already displayed on screen.

Let me explain this . Suppose I have typed a letter in a certain font style on the screen.

[image: 100% pixel density]

On click of a button I need to change the pixel density on the text to change like this

Is this possible with Java.

[image: 75% pixel density]

Comment: Once displayed, it's just an image. Not a font. A font is a description of the way a character should be drawn. It's not a displayed character.

Comment: So that means there is no feasibility for this feature ?

Comment: That means that it's not clear what you want to do. If you just want to change the image that appears on screen, you should look into image-manipulation algorithms (such as drawing a grid over the image). If you want to manipulate fonts, it's a different issue.

Comment: I needed to know if my requirement was feasible , if not I will try some other way . If wanted to change the font of the text after it was displayed  just as it showed in the screen shot . I do not understand what is not clear in this very simple scheme of things.

Comment: Did you want to change the **font** (which is a set of instructions "draw a line up, draw a line down" stored in a special file), or the **image**? If you don't understand the distinction, I can't help you any further.

Comment: I want the font style to change when a new font style is selected . The existing text as well as the text typed in next till the next font change should reflect that change . This is the requirement . I need a way to  acheive this . Which one of the 2 ways you mentioned  should be appropriate for this task.